# a beginner in vb.net.. working on a login form

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = JOKENCONN()

    Public Function JOKENCONN() As MySqlConnection
        Return New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database =studentdb")

    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GroupBox1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub LBLLOGIN_CLICK(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbllogin.Click
        lbllogin.Text = "Login"
        lbllogin.Text = "Login"
        lblname.Text = "Hi, Guest"
        If lbllogin.Text = "Login" Then
            GroupBox1.Enabled = True

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNOK_CLICK(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnok.Click
        Dim Sql As String
        Dim publictable As New DataTable
        Try
            If txtusername.Text = "" And txtpass.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Password or username is incorrect!")
            Else
                Sql = "select ' from tbluseraccount where username='" & txtusername.Text & "' and userpassword='" & txtpass.Text & "'"

                With cmd
                    .Connection = con

                End With

                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                da.Fill(publictable)
                If publictable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim user_type As String
                    user_type = publictable.Rows(0).Item(4)
                    Name = publictable.Rows(0).Item(1)
                    If user_type = "Admin" Then
                        MsgBox("Welcome " & Name & "you login as Administrator")
                        lbllogin.Text = "logout"
                        lblname.Text = "Hi, " & Name

                        GroupBox1.Enabled = False
                        txtusername.Text = ""
                        txtpass.Text = ""
                    ElseIf user_type = "cetakoradi2" Then
                        MsgBox("Welcome " & Name & "you login as cetakoradi2")
                        lbllogin.Text = "logout"
                        lblname.Text = "Hi, " & Name
                        GroupBox1.Enabled = False
                        txtusername.Text = ""
                        txtpass.Text = ""
                    Else

                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox("contact administrator to register")
                    txtusername.Text = ""
                    txtpass.Text = ""

                End If

                da.Dispose()

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con.Close()


        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

this the error i received

ExecuteReader CommandText property has not been properly initialized

i really need help on that. this is the error that i receives. thank you

Comment: There are two things in programming which commonly result in security issues that are so prevalent and so important, it's not okay to to even do them for learning, proof of concept, or example code. This breaks both. Before doing anything else, go lookup how to use Parameterized queries to avoid **SQL Injection**, and how to use BCrypt to **hash your passwords**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the name of the field represented in `publictable.Rows(0).Item(4)` is named *user_type*, then you could use the following:

```
'Declare the object that will be returned from the command
Dim user_type As String

'Declare the connection object
Dim con As OleDbConnection

'Wrap code in Try/Catch
Try
    'Set the connection object to a new instance
    con = JOKENCONN()

    'Create a new instance of the command object
    Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT user_type FROM tbluseraccount WHERE username=@0 AND userpassword=@1;", con)
        'Paramterize the query
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", txtusername.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", txtpass.Text)

        'Open the connection
        con.Open()

        'Use ExecuteScalar to return a single value
        user_type = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        'Close the connection
        con.Close()
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    'Display the error
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
Finally
    'Check if the connection object was initialized
    If con IsNot Nothing Then
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            'Close the connection if it was left open(exception thrown)
            con.Close()
        End If

        'Dispose of the connection object
        con.Dispose()
    End If
End Try

If (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(user_type)) Then
    'Failed login
ElseIf (user_type = "Admin") Then
    'Admin login
ElseIf (user_type = "cetakoradi2") Then
    'cetakoradi2 login
Else
    'Not a failed login, but also not an admin or cetakoradi2 either
End If
```

What this code does is setup a parameterized query to get just the user_type where the username and password match the parameterized values. Since there should only ever be one record that matches those conditions (presumably) then we're able to use ExecuteScalar to return just that single field value.

Comment: Upvote for demonstrating parameters but how about using the .Add method. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to reinforce the point, [MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteScalar.htm), just like the Microsoft counterparts, *"executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Extra columns or rows are ignored"* and returns *" The first column of the first row in the result set, or a **null reference** if the result set is empty "*.

The proposed code by @David checks for this condition using `IsNullOrWhitespace`.

`ExecuteScalar` is effective but retrieves only one value at a time.
The other option pursued by the OP is to return a `datarow`, which is a valid approach if he wants to return several fields at the same time. In his example he retrieves two fields for variables `user_type` and `Name` respectively.

Be careful, VB.net like any other programming language has [reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/). If you do not take a habit of using good **naming conventions** you might one day stumble upon on one of those keywords, possibly hit obscure bugs. `Name` is not a good name for a variable and has the potential for confusion since every object has a name property.

To address the specific issue at hand, the error message `ExecuteReader CommandText property has not been properly initialized` is self-explanatory. What should have been done is simply:

```
With cmd
    .Connection = con
    .CommandText = Sql
End With
```

You defined a command, but did not tell it what to do. In your code variable `Sql` is defined but unused. With this missing bit there is a chance the code will work as expected.

---

Small details:

Not critical, but his condition does not work if you enter whitespace for example:

```
If txtusername.Text = "" And txtpass.Text = "" Then
```

An improvement is to simply **trim** the values from the textboxes:

```
If txtusername.Text.Trim = "" And txtpass.Text.Trim = "" Then
```

But I think what you want is not an `And` but `Or`. I don't think you want to allow logins without passwords.

---

Instead of doing multiple `If/ElseIf` you could have a `Select Case`